# Can I Execute a Jar-File that contains JavaCV 1.0 on a Raspberry PI?

Tags: opencv, java

Is this possible to run a Jar-File that contains JavaCV 1.0 on a Raspberry PI?

Answer (score 1):

JavaCV is basically a wrapper around OpenCV and other related liberaries. There are a lot tutorial out there describing how to install und use OpenCV on the raspberry pi. So (without testing and knowing it exactly) I see no reason why JavaCV shouldn't run on a Raspberry pi.